# Saving files to sub directory with imagejpeg

Tags: php, image

I have a php file that creates a thumbnail using an uploaded image.
If i use

```
imagejpeg( $tmp_img, $_FILES["file"]["name"] );
```

it saves the picture without any issues to the same directory that the upload.php file is in.

I want to save the picture to

```
imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "uploads/thumbnails/" + $_FILES["file"]["name"] );
```

where the uploads folder is in the same directory as the upload.php file. But this doesnt seem to work... where have i gone wrong?

Comment: Be aware of the security problems with this solution. For example: the user can overwrite any file under your root directory. Or imagine it's called .php and there is php code in the image's comment - it will get executed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the `.` in place of `+` in:

```
imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "uploads/thumbnails/" + $_FILES["file"]["name"] );
                                           ^
```

`.` is the string concatenation operator in PHP.

Comment: Opps :D. Cheers man, spent an hour looking in all the wrong places.